# What is the difference between JS strings that use a single quote vs concatenation?

Tags: javascript

I am at a complete loss for what's going on here.
What is the difference between the two following strings?

```js
var email = "From: a@gmail.com\r\n";
email += "To: a@yahoo.com\r\n";
email += "Subject: Hello\r\n";
email += "\r\nEmpty";

console.log(email);

var email2 = 'From: a@gmail.com\r\n \
To: a@yahoo.com\r\n \
Subject: Hello\r\n \
\r\nEmpty';

console.log(email2);
```

Comment: Run the snippet - the difference should be pretty obvious. Remove the two additional spaces and the strings are identical

Comment: This difference (or lack thereof assuming the extra spaces are a typo) has nothing to do with the quotes being single or double, b.t.w.  And you should check out the new multi-line-enabled template literals (with backticks).

Comment: Thank you, thank you ... I am using AWS Lambda so output looks a little different in their log window.